# Does my idea infringe on this financial calendar patent?

Tags: us8423452, us8380623

Patent in question: https://www.google.com/patents/US8423452

(Related patent: https://www.google.com/patents/US8380623)

Assume I know nothing about patents or the law surrounding them.

One feature of my idea is to track your transactions across one or more financial accounts and display them on a calendar, allowing for the input of future transactions that will occur. This would then show the balance for every day, whether that be positive or negative.

Does this infringe on what is defined in the patent (or the related patent)? If so, how can I change my application so it does not or what advice could you offer me to stay within the confines of the law? It seems like these patents cover a lot of ground in terms of preventing anyone else from even touching the financial monitoring/planning realm.

CLAIM 1  of the '452 patent

> 1. A computer-assisted method for alerting a user of a potential negative balance condition in a financial account, the method comprising:
>
>    estimating, using a processor, a future account balance of the financial account based on at least one real time representation of an account transaction and at least one future account transaction;
>
>    determining, using the processor, whether the future account balance will be a negative value;
>
>    generating for display, using the processor, an alert, in a graphical format, to the user that signifies when the future account balance is the negative value; and
>      rescheduling an automatic bill payment from the financial account when the future account balance is the negative value, wherein the rescheduling causes, in real time, data in a source to be changed such that the automatic bill payment is scheduled to occur on a rescheduled date.

CLAIM 1 of the '623 patent

> 1. A computer-assisted method for facilitating financial savings, the method comprising:
>
>    accepting, using a processor, a funds transfer request by a user of an amount of funds between a funding account and at least one receiving account, wherein the funding account and the receiving account are separate accounts;
>
>    accepting, from the user, using the processor, a designation of an intended purpose of use of the amount of funds and a date of intended use of the amount of funds;
>
>    transferring the amount of funds from the funding account to the at least one receiving account;
>
>    generating, using the processor, for display on a graphical banking interface, a graphical representation of the designation of the intended purpose of use of the amount of funds; and
>      transferring the amount of funds from the at least one receiving account to the funding account on the date of intended use.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. We are primarlity set up for two types of questions. One om-topic category is requests for help finding prior art to specific patents or patent applications. The other om-topic category are questions about the U.S. patent system. You might edit your question to  turn it into a question about the patent system and be more on-topic.

Comment: Thanks for the help, George. I guess I will have to request help from a patent attorney for my situation, then?